# Аналог CreateDirectoryA для Linux

Tags: c++, linux, g++

Посоветуйте аналог CreateDirectoryA для Линукса. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
//...
boost::filesystem::create_directories("/any/dir/a/b/c");
```

---

А вообще, в Linux есть **[mkdir](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=mkdir&category=3&russian=5)**, и **[system()](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=system&category=3&russian=2)** - которые позволят вам сделать следующее:

```
system("mkdir -p /any/dir/a/b/c")
```

---

Взял код с enSO:

Автор утверждает, что код работает и на вантузе и на Linux:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h> // stat
#include <errno.h>    // errno, ENOENT, EEXIST
#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <direct.h>   // _mkdir
#endif

bool isDirExist(const std::string& path)
{
#if defined(_WIN32)
    struct _stat info;
    if (_stat(path.c_str(), &info) != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return (info.st_mode & _S_IFDIR) != 0;
#else 
    struct stat info;
    if (stat(path.c_str(), &info) != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return (info.st_mode & S_IFDIR) != 0;
#endif
}

bool makePath(const std::string& path)
{
#if defined(_WIN32)
    int ret = _mkdir(path.c_str());
#else
    mode_t mode = 0755;
    int ret = mkdir(path.c_str(), mode);
#endif
    if (ret == 0)
        return true;

    switch (errno)
    {
    case ENOENT:
        // parent didn't exist, try to create it
        {
            int pos = path.find_last_of('/');
            if (pos == std::string::npos)
#if defined(_WIN32)
                pos = path.find_last_of('\\');
            if (pos == std::string::npos)
#endif
                return false;
            if (!makePath( path.substr(0, pos) ))
                return false;
        }
        // now, try to create again
#if defined(_WIN32)
        return 0 == _mkdir(path.c_str());
#else 
        return 0 == mkdir(path.c_str(), mode);
#endif

    case EEXIST:
        // done!
        return isDirExist(path);

    default:
        return false;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* ARGV[])
{
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "creating " << ARGV[i] << " ... " << (makePath(ARGV[i]) ? "OK" : "failed") << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ makePath 1/2 folderA/folderB/folderC
creating 1/2 ... OK
creating folderA/folderB/folderC ... OK
```

---

Оффтоп: я начинаю приунывать, когда вижу *погроммистов*, которые начинают *погроммировать* на винде(

---

Comment: А если создание с переменной? К примеру как писал для винды.     std::string kor = ("somedir/");
    CreateDirectoryA(kor.c_str(), NULL);

Comment: Спокойствие, только спокойствие :) - даже на Винде нормальные программисты спокойно используют `_mkdir()`. Ну, а если человек для этого использует `system("md...")` - то тут уж все равно, под какой операционкой такое чудить...

Comment: а правильным ответом было простое `mkdir(2)`...